# Надо ли как-то компилировать файл сервера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, build

У меня есть фронт, написанный на react, собранный в билд. Мне нужно как-то транслировать/компилировать сервер, чтобы он был в одном файле, и поместить его в в этот билд? Или как правильно все это оформить для заливки на виртуальный сервер?

Answer (score 0):

По сути это два отдельных проекта backend и frontend. Если вы упаковали frontend при помощи gulp или webpack. То можете воспользоваться ими же для упаковки backend. т.е в результате у вас будет два проекта для продакшена оба упакованы (не скомпилированы).

По поводу заливки. То заливать думаю вы будите два проекта, а не один. Если хотите в один, то логично собрать в один проект.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем код сервера выкладывать на фронт?  Это как минимум противоречит постулатам безопасности. А так, код сервера как отдельны проект заливается на сервер (в идеале настроить заливку через тимсити). И на него уже отправляются запросы. Так же может быть некоторая разница между серверным js и фронтовым (например тот же fs - его на фронте вообще нет) в общем на фронте этот код может вообще не запуститься.